# Send data pipeline logs to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a cloud formation template for the data pipeline. The only option I see under that is to send logs to the S3 bucket like:

```
-
              Key: "pipelineLogUri"
              StringValue: "s3://logs-for-pipeline/"
```

Is there a way to send these logs to CloudWatch instead of the S3 bucket?